# What's the difference between "day" and "date"?

Tags: differences, nouns, dates

*Day* may refer to:

- the day of the week (e.g., Monday, Tuesday);
- the day of the month (e.g, 2nd day of February);
- a unit of time (e.g., *this task would take 2 days to complete*).

A date on the other hand usually has the month and the year along with the day: the 21st February 2011. It also has a fixed quality I think. 
I was wondering if there are any other differences between *day* and *date*, and when it's correct to choose one over the other. By that I mean I am interested in the meanings and usage of date that pertain to time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When used in reference to time, *date* almost exclusively refers to a specific 24 hour period that begins at midnight and ends at 11:59pm.  When used this way, the *date* will be specified with a year (CE or BCE), the name of the month, and the number of the day within that month.  The day number is a positive whole number that may be used in ordinal form (first, second, third, etc.)  The name of the weekday is rarely referenced when referring to a date.

When setting up an appointment, you typically use the term '*date*' if the appointment is a long time away or in a formal business setting.  When making appointments with friends, especially if they are happening within one week's time, you would use the term '*day*'.

You ask a friend "What day do you want to have lunch?"  The receptionist at your doctor's office will ask you "What date would you like to have your next appointment?"

Answer (score 6):

Date is a much more wide-ranging word. It can mean:

- A precise time (as you have said)
- A pre-arranged meeting (and as a similar verb - 'We're dating.')
- As a verb, to assign an age to something

Not to mention a few more archaic meanings.

And of course it's also a fruit!

Comment: Yeah, that's a good one I did not think of date as a fruit. But I am interested in the meanings and usage of date that pertain to time.

Comment: Well, there's 3 for you at least. :)

Answer (score 2):

a day is a constant while a date keeps on changing over time, for example Tuesday the 30th of December 2008 was on the fourth week. however,the fourth week of December 2011 presents us with a Tuesday with 27th as its date. this shows us that the day "Tuesday" continue to appear in fourth week, but with a different date. this then provokes the question why do people celebrate birth dates instead of birth days?

Comment: You have it backwards; people celebrate birthdays rather than birth-dates.